# Post more than 1 picture in a Facebook Post

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, sdk

This is my code. It works fine, but I can only post once for each image :

```
[params setObject:_selectedPhoto forKey:@"source"];          
FBRequestConnection *connect = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] initWithTimeout:30];

// Creo al richiesta di upload foto 
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos",nomeAlbum] parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Can I put more images for each connection?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not implementing multiple Photo's sharing in iOS. But i read some what on it. Yes, you can send multiple images on facebook using batch POST request see the [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) doc

also read [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.upload/) as well.

The format of your POST message is,

```
curl 
     -F 'access_token=…' \
     -F 'batch=[{"method":"POST","relative_url":"me/photos","body":"message=My cat photo","attached_files":"file1"},{"method":"POST","relative_url":"me/photos","body":"message=My dog photo","attached_files":"file2"},]' \
     -F 'file1=@cat.gif' \
     -F 'file2=@dog.jpg' \
    https://graph.facebook.com
```

Read the point **Uploading binary data** from given link.

There are also some limitation for batch,

> We currently limit the number of requests which can be in a batch to
>   50, but each call within the batch is counted separately for the
>   purposes of calculating API call limits and resource limits. For
>   example, a batch of 10 API calls will count as 10 calls and each call
>   within the batch contributes to CPU resource limits in the same
>   manner.

Comment: many thanks for the fast answer, unfortunately I can not understand how I can make bath with xcode, no one has a small sample code?

thanks Claudio

Comment: Ok. Then take your time to complete bath with XCode then let me know.

Comment: At the end I was able to use the batch in IOS, but also by uploading 2 photos in a batch Fb performs two separate post! will never be possible??